# Websocket Client doesn't connect to Server when hosted on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, websocket

**Background:**

I am running a Java WebSocket server on my Amazon EC2 instance that acts as a relay between an Android app and website.

I'm hosting the website on my EC2 using apache2 (put the contents of an npm build folder into /var/www/html) and can connect to it fine through the public IPv4 address or the IPv4 DNS. The website is a React App.

I have the WS server running on my inet address on port 8888, with TCP port 8887 and UDP port 8886 and in my Security Group I have a rule for Custom TCP on port range 8888,8887,8886 with anywhere as the source type. My website's WS manager is set to connect to "ws://myinetaddress:8888". Running the WS server using `java -jar server.jar` works fine.

**Problem:**

Whenever I try to connect the website and WS server, I get these errors in my sources tab[image: error message]. There are no errors on the server side.

Checking on https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ shows that
**Remote Adress**: myinetaddress **Port address**: 8888 is closed even though when `netstat -tulpn` shows that myinetaddress:8888 is in the LISTEN state.
[image]

Everything runs perfectly fine when I run the website locally with `npm start` and run WS server locally, with the WS manager in the website set to connect to "we://localhost:8888"

**What I've Tried:**

- Allowing all TCP in my inbound rules.
- Using my
  Public IPv4 address in my WS server code (throws error imminently)
- Running the website via `serve -s build` (can't even connect to website)

I'm very new to all this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your netstat is showing only ipv6?  Is it possible you are trying to connect to your service using ipv4 while the application is listening only on ipv6?